# What is the correct use of the 'row' class when using several div sections stacked onto each other?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm sure I'm missing something very trivial, but I've got mentally exhausted trying to figure it out.

I got a page with 3 basic sections like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="topHead">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

I read that you're supposed to keep `.row` elements within a `.container` or `.container-fluid`. What is the right usage when you have several sections and you want to use the grid system? Should each div described above use the `container` class?

For instance, I'm using something similar to this:

```
<body class="container">
    <div id="topHead">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="logo.png">
        </div>
        <div id="site-title">
            <h2 class="text-center">My Website</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="left-menu" class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="main" class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>My Website.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Should I never use nested `.row` sections?

Sorry if I'm being quite vague. I'm having a lot of trouble to describe what is happening, but it basically boils down to a lot of padding issues when I use the `row` class. I want to use the grid system, and at times use another grid within one of them, a grid within a grid.

Here's a picture of the behaviour I'm experiencing:
[image]

I know I have something messed up, but the more I try to debug this, the more I seem to be screwing up the grid.

**EDIT:**

In this one I use only one container, the one in the `<body>` tag.

[image]

**EDIT2:**

Here's the fiddle of the images above. https://jsfiddle.net/kbqqfn0k/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i see your main problem that you use nested .container class. You should use only one for outer block.

e.g.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- etc -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPD:

the same goes to row class. No need to use

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/y804nyjn/1/

UPD2:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- etc -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <!-- etc -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <!-- do not use .row class, unless you are using col-X-* inside-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added another picture where I use only one `.container`.

Comment: so probably you have some overwrites in your custom css. Create a fiddle with all your styles

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kbqqfn0k/2/ I changed the background to black, as I don't know how to upload the background image I'm using. Should have the same effect. The one class that may seem like it could affect this is `no-padding`, but even if I remove it, the problem persists.

Comment: see the answer updated with the fiddle. Also please note there is no need in no-padding class if you are using bootstrap grid the right way.

Comment: I use `no-padding` cause the space in between columns is too big for the content I'm trying to put in the main section.

Comment: Ok, that solves the mess I have, but now my main question, what is the proper way to use `.row`? Cause as soon as I put one, the whole thing gets shifted to one side or the other. I want to use more `div`s that will be stacked onto each other, and for that I had the idea of using `.row` for each block, but this creates the mess I previously mentioned.

Comment: i think you should read up on bootstrap doc one more time :) meanwhile see me my answer updated one more time

Comment: I'll mark your answer as the solution, although I'm still VERY confused how to do this properly. I'll figure it out when I'm not so stressed. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score -1):

In bootstrap.min.css you need to comment this three lines or create new css and add these three lines as !important

```
.row {
/* margin-left: -15px; */
/* margin-right: -15px; */
}
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
min-height: 1px;
padding-left: 15px;
/* padding-right: 15px; */
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That makes the padding issue go away, that's for sure, but I'm more concerned of what is the proper use of `row`, as I'm clearly not understanding how it is supposed to be used.